# Measuring speed up of a multi threaded C program (implementation using Pthreads)

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I currently have a multi-threaded C program coded using Pthreads which uses 2 threads. I want to increase the no. of threads and measure speed up upon doing so. I would like to run my code in an automated manner where the no. of threads used keeps getting incremented and I want to graphically display running times of my code. I would love it if I could get a clue in on how to do so especially on how to automate the entire process and plotting it graphically. Here is my code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 2
#define VECTOR_SIZE 40

struct DOTdata
{
    /* data */
    long X[VECTOR_SIZE];
    long Y[VECTOR_SIZE];
    long sum;
    long compute_length;
};

struct DOTdata dotstr;
pthread_mutex_t mutex_sum;

void *calcDOT(void *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long vec_index;

    for(vec_index = 0 ; vec_index < VECTOR_SIZE ; vec_index++){
        dotstr.X[vec_index] = vec_index + 1;
        dotstr.Y[vec_index] = vec_index + 2; 
    }

    dotstr.sum = 0;
    dotstr.compute_length = VECTOR_SIZE/NUM_THREADS;

    pthread_t call_thread[NUM_THREADS];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    void *status;

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_sum, NULL);

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    long i;

    for(i = 0 ; i < NUM_THREADS ; i++){
        pthread_create(&call_thread[i], &attr, calcDOT, (void *)i);
    }

    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

    for (i = 0 ; i < NUM_THREADS ; i++){
        pthread_join(call_thread[i], &status);
    }

    printf("Resultant X*Y is %ld\n", dotstr.sum);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_sum);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *calcDOT(void *thread_id)
{
    long vec_index;
    long start_index;
    long end_index;
    long length;
    long offset;
    long sum = 0;

    offset = (long)thread_id;
    length = dotstr.compute_length;

    start_index = offset * length;
    end_index = (start_index + length) - 1;

    for(vec_index = start_index ; vec_index < end_index ; vec_index++){
        sum += (dotstr.X[vec_index] * dotstr.Y[vec_index]);
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_sum);
    dotstr.sum += sum;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_sum);

    pthread_exit((void *)thread_id);

}
```

I would like to increment my NUM_THREADS parameter and run it after each increment, record the execution time after each increment and plot a graph of execution time vs number of threads.

Comment: Which OS? And to make it clear, have you already managed to make your application work with an arbitrary number of threads or you're also seeking help for that?

Comment: I have written my code which uses n threads although a constant throughout its execution cycle. My OS is macOS Sierra.

Comment: I can vary my NUM_THREADS parameter and run it separately, but I want to automate the process, record the execution time of each cycle and graphically display it.

Comment: You can modify your code to take the number of threads from the command-line or standard input. Then you can write a script to call your program several times. I'm not versed in Mac, but I think you can use Bash and `time` to measure your program.

Comment: Or instead of modifying your program, an easier solution would be to make your script supply `NUM_THREADS` to the compiler as a macro. In GCC you can use the option `-D` for that. Write a script that will compile your program with different numbers of threads, run it, and measure the running time.

Comment: If this isn't enough to help you find your way, I think your question would be better received in either the Unix or the "Ask Different" community. Check them both to see which one would suit you better.

Comment: Thanks for the input @g

Comment: this line: `dotstr.compute_length = VECTOR_SIZE/NUM_THREADS;` will not work as expected.  This is because it is using an integer divide, to any remainder will be truncated.  So this will only work correctly when NUM_THREADS exactly divides into VECTOR_SIZE.   When NUM_THREADS is larger than VECTOR_SIZE, the number of threads will be 0

Comment: the posted code can eliminate all the `attr` statements and just pass NULL as the second parameter to pThreadCreate()

Comment: regarding this line: `pthread_create(&call_thread[i], &attr, calcDOT, (void *)i);`  in general, the last parameter should be the address of the data, not casting the data as if it were a pointer.  Suggest: `pthread_create(&call_thread[i], &attr, calcDOT, (void *)&i);  Then this line: `offset = (long)thread_id;` should be: `offset = (long)(*thread_id);`

Comment: the posted code is not using the returned value from the threads, to avoid clutter, suggest using: `pthread_exit( NULL );`  and `pthread_join(  call_thread[i], NULL );`

Comment: the posted code needs to be checking the returned value from: `pthread_create()` `pthread_join()` to assure they were successful.

Comment: this line: `pthread_mutex_t mutex_sum;` would be better written as: `pthread_mutex_t mutex_sum = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;` and eliminate the call to `pthread_mutex_init()`

Comment: an important thing to note: breaking the calculation into numerous threads will SLOW DOWN the program due to context switching, etc.

Comment: `(void *)i` this results in implementation defined behaviour. Didn't you notice some warning during compilation?

Answer (score 2):

I tried a naive approach by increasing the number of threads, timing it with `time.h` and plotting it with gnuplot. Each iteration we double the number of threads and we print the time for an iteration. We use gnuplot to display a graph with number of threads on the x-axis and execution time on the y-axis

[image]

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 2
#define VECTOR_SIZE 40

struct DOTdata {
    /* data */
    long X[VECTOR_SIZE];
    long Y[VECTOR_SIZE];
    long sum;
    long compute_length;
};

struct DOTdata dotstr;
pthread_mutex_t mutex_sum;

void *calcDOT(void *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double xvals[VECTOR_SIZE / NUM_THREADS];
    double yvals[VECTOR_SIZE / NUM_THREADS];
    int index = 0;
    for (int count = NUM_THREADS; count < VECTOR_SIZE / NUM_THREADS; count = count * 2) {

        clock_t begin = clock();

        long vec_index;

        for (vec_index = 0; vec_index < VECTOR_SIZE; vec_index++) {
            dotstr.X[vec_index] = vec_index + 1;
            dotstr.Y[vec_index] = vec_index + 2;
        }

        dotstr.sum = 0;
        dotstr.compute_length = VECTOR_SIZE / count;

        pthread_t call_thread[count];
        pthread_attr_t attr;
        void *status;

        pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_sum, NULL);

        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

        long i;

        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            pthread_create(&call_thread[i], &attr, calcDOT, (void *) i);
        }

        pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            pthread_join(call_thread[i], &status);
        }

        printf("Resultant X*Y is %ld\n", dotstr.sum);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_sum);
        clock_t end = clock();
        double time_spent = (double) (end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        printf("time spent: %f NUM_THREADS: %d\n", time_spent, count);
        xvals[index] = count;
        yvals[index] = time_spent;
        index++;
    }

    FILE * gnuplotPipe = popen ("gnuplot -persistent", "w");

    fprintf(gnuplotPipe, "plot '-' \n");

    for (int i = 0; i < VECTOR_SIZE / NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        fprintf(gnuplotPipe, "%lf %lf\n", xvals[i], yvals[i]);
    }

    fprintf(gnuplotPipe, "e");


    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *calcDOT(void *thread_id) {
    long vec_index;
    long start_index;
    long end_index;
    long length;
    long offset;
    long sum = 0;

    offset = (long) thread_id;
    length = dotstr.compute_length;

    start_index = offset * length;
    end_index = (start_index + length) - 1;

    for (vec_index = start_index; vec_index < end_index; vec_index++) {
        sum += (dotstr.X[vec_index] * dotstr.Y[vec_index]);
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_sum);
    dotstr.sum += sum;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_sum);

    pthread_exit((void *) thread_id);

}
```

Output

```
Resultant X*Y is 20900
time spent: 0.000155 NUM_THREADS: 2
Resultant X*Y is 19860
time spent: 0.000406 NUM_THREADS: 4
Resultant X*Y is 17680
time spent: 0.000112 NUM_THREADS: 8
Resultant X*Y is 5712
time spent: 0.000587 NUM_THREADS: 16
```